# Where are python packages stored in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I need to find the python packages within my virtual environment.

When I run `pip freeze` I can see all the packages in the virtual environment.

However, when I `cd ./venv/` and run `tree Pillow` (or manually search) I cannot find any installed package.

Any idea where they are stored?

Comment: you can try `PIL` instead of `Pillow`

Comment: You can also import the module and then use `module.__path__` to see where it is stored.

Comment: Easy to say: openen the interactive interpreter, import a package, type its name and hit Return.

Comment: `pip show --files pillow`

Comment: search in `./venv/lib/pythonx.x/site-packages`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask *pip* to tell you where it installed the project with the following command:

```
$ path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip show --files Pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

from virtualenv do `pip -V`

It will be in : `<virtual env root dir>  + lib`

example from my terminal

```
(vams_test) C:\VAMS\jiras\vams>pip -V
pip 19.2.3 from c:\vams\code\copy_v0.1\vams_test\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```